# How do you handle the "could not parse code block as Rust code" rustdoc warning?

Tags: rust, rustdoc

I'm writing some rust doc examples (that are compiling):

````
/// ```rust
/// # #[macro_use]
/// # extern crate ...
/// ...
/// ```
````

But `cargo doc` gives me this [incorrect] warning:

````
warning: could not parse code block as Rust code
   --> srml/support/src/dispatch.rs:105:5
    |
105 |   ///    ```rust
    |  ________^
106 | | /// # #[macro_use]
    | |_
    |
    = note: error from rustc: unknown start of token: `
help: mark blocks that do not contain Rust code as text
    |
105 | ///    ```textrust
    |        ^^^^^^^
````

Should I just suppress this warning.. or is something off here?

Comment: What is the actual code that reproduces this error? Try to add a [MCVE] to your question.

Answer (score 1):

You fix the error by using valid Rust code inside the code block.

---

This reproduces the problem:

````
///    ```rust
///
///    ```
pub fn foo() {}
````

Don't add spurious whitespace before your code blocks. In Markdown, four spaces counts as the beginning of code, so you have actually done the equivalent of the HTML:

````html
<code>```rust  ```</code>
````

As it tells you, ```` ``` ```` isn't valid Rust code.

Comment: Oh, I didn't spot the extra spaces in the actual error messages. Good catch!